# Request GPS permission using Capacitor (Ionic)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, capacitor

I'm coding an app using Ionic & Capacitor that requires GPS. I want to know if there is a way to invoke this dialogue and enable GPS

[image]

using capacitor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Capacitor 3 all plugins that require permission have methods for requesting permissions and checking status of permissions.

So, in `@capacitor/geolocation` plugin you can call `Geolocation.requestPermissions();` for both iOS and Android.

Old answer for Capacitor 2 and older:

You can use Geolocation plugin itself to request it's permissions like this: `Capacitor.Plugins.Geolocation.requestPermissions();` on Android. But it's not possible on iOS.

Anyway, it's always recommended to let the plugins work themselves, when you try to use `getCurrentPosition` or `watchPosition`, the plugin will automatically request the permission if not granted.

Comment: I'm getting a Geolocation.requestPermissions() is not a function

Comment: on iOS? it's Android only

Comment: It’s only possible on Android. Anyway, as I mentioned, the geolocation plugin will prompt right before using it, not sure why do you want to prompt without using it.

Comment: I want to verify if it was granted or denied so I can notify the user accordingly

Comment: Next release of Capacitor will include a plugin that allows to check if certain permissions are granted

Comment: It is possible now with plugin `Permissions` @jcesarmobile

Comment: That plugin is only for querying status, not for requesting permission

Comment: I'm confused by the Capacitor plugins having `requestPermissions()`.  I find it does nothing on Android and only returns an empty object literal.  Doesn't seem to matter if permissions have been approved or denied it's always an object literal result.  I was expecting that it would show a native prompt to approve/deny permissions.  Isn't that what should occur, or am I missing something?  Capacitor docs could sure use some explanation.  I have to make an empty app for everything to test what occurs before figuring out how to implement it properly in an actual app.

Comment: @mtpultz look at this: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/geolocation#permissionstate

Comment: Can you give more information ? @BrunoPolo

Comment: @BorisD See this https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/apis/permissions

Comment: @BrunoPolo are you sure its not only to verify?

Comment: @BorisD I was replying jcesarmobile comment. And YES it is only for querying. He said "a plugin that allows to check if certain permissions are granted"

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this to your AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

Comment: Hello, I have added this. It gave me the popup on first run but i want the popup to appear every time a user opens my app so they dont have to drag down the notification drawer. Kind of like in Careem app there is a button to enable GPS

Comment: maybe this can help u. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766481/how-to-programmatically-enable-and-disable-gps-in-ionic-framework-or-cordova

Comment: not working for me :/ there seems to be no solid do it all plugin for this kind of functionality

Comment: have you tried the answer of  SM3RKY? I think its the best solution.